# Where can I access annual reports of the registrar-general for England after 1920?

Tags: england, vital-records, statistics

The annual reports of the registrar-general relating to births, marriage, and deaths in England and Wales were published every year since civil registration began, and are available at the [Histpop](http://www.histpop.org/ohpr/servlet/Browse?path=Browse/Registrar%20General%20%28by%20date%29/1911-1920&active=yes&titlepos=20) website up to 1920. However, there are no reports after that date. Does anyone know where or how one could access later reports, such as for the 1920s and 1930s?

I find these reports useful for a number of reasons, some of which are related to genealogy, as well as broader historical/epidemiological/health related interests. With relation to genealogy, it is interesting to examine trends of births and deaths in certain localities to put my ancestors in a better context.

Comment: "Public domain" is not a synonym for "widely available" -- see [Public library, not public domain](http://www.legalgenealogist.com/blog/2013/04/19/public-library-not-public-domain/) by The Legal Genealogist (posted 19 Apr 2013). The question of when works enter the public domain will vary widely depending on the country involved.  I would research that question rather than assuming the date ranges in another country are the same as in the USA.  If you need to reproduce something, look at the terms of use and rights statements.  If not, does that statement need to be in the question?

Comment: Specifically in this case the documents are likely subject to Crown Copyright which means the copyright will expire fifty years from the end of the year in which they were published.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The British Library appear to have two collections, [one covering 1838 to 1920](http://explore.bl.uk/primo_library/libweb/action/display.do?ct=display&fn=search&doc=BLL01014503759&indx=2&recIds=BLL01014503759&recIdxs=1&elementId=0&renderMode=poppedOut&displayMode=full&dscnt=0&fctN=facet_creator&rfnGrp=1&frbrVersion=&scp.scps=scope%3A%28BLCONTENT%29&fctV=Great+Britain.+General+Register+Office&tab=local_tab&dstmp=1428425045532&srt=rank&mode=Basic&vl(488279563UI0)=any&tb=t&rfnGrpCounter=1&vl(freeText0)=annual%20report%20of%20the%20registrar-general&vid=BLVU1&frbg=&dum=true&tabs=detailsTab&gathStatTab=true) and a [second covering 1921 to 1968](http://explore.bl.uk/primo_library/libweb/action/display.do?ct=display&fn=search&doc=BLL01001109343&indx=1&recIds=BLL01001109343&recIdxs=0&elementId=0&renderMode=poppedOut&displayMode=full&dscnt=0&onCampus=false&frbrVersion=&query=rid%2Cexact%2CBLL01001109343&scp.scps=&dym=false&dstmp=1428425203746&group=ALL&vl(freeText0)=BLL01001109343&vid=BLVU1&institution=BL&tabs=detailsTab&gathStatTab=true) when they seem to have ceased according to the British Library catalog entry.

The first of those groups appears to be what Histpop has - it seems that after that there was a change to the way they were published.

At least some years seem to be available at the National Archives although sometimes in odd places, for example [1971](http://discovery.nationalarchives.gov.uk/details/r/C622758) is in the papers of the Sizewell B inquiry! Not sure how that squares with them ending in 1968 either.

In any case the title seems to have changed after 1920 to "Registrar General: Statistical review of England and Wales NNNN" which may be why you have been having trouble finding them.

Answer (score 2):

not England but it may be of interest that Ireland & Northern Ireland reports are available here covering 1864 to present day:
Ireland/Northern Ireland Reports 1887 onwards from http://www.nisra.gov.uk/demography/default.asp57.htm
Ireland 1864 onwards: http://cso.ie/en/statistics/birthsdeathsandmarriages/archive/annualreportsonmarriagesbirthsanddeathsinirelandfrom1864to2000/